# Discoloration on edges of pink syngonium leaves

Tags: plant-health

I have a pink syngonium plant and some discoloration that feels damp to the touch has started to appear on the edges of some of the leaves. Should I be worried about this? What could be causing it?

I live in a basement apartment so I have a grow light over it. I've been told to keep the intensity of the lamp down and to give it around 3 hours of light per day. I've also been told to wait until the soil is completely dry before watering. Is this ok? Could the amount of light that I'm giving it be causing this?

[image: Discoloration 1]
[image: Discoloration 2]
<sub>(source: [i.ibb.co](https://i.ibb.co/FKBPXdC/IMG-20210917-095111-resized-20210917-095827317.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Looks like tipburn, look at the other leaves as well. Either a bit too dry, or too much salts (fertiliser etc) in the soil.

Hopefully an expert on this plant will answer, maybe overwater and drain out just once.